Is it known that $\mathsf{E} \subset \mathsf{NP} \subset \mathsf{SIZE}[n^k]$ is false?
Is it known that $\mathsf{E} \subset \mathsf{NP} \subset \mathsf{SIZE}[n^k]$ is false?
It is easy to show that the relaxed version ($\mathsf{E} \subset \mathsf{NP}$ and $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{NP}} \subset \mathsf{SIZE}[n^k]$) is false, as $\mathsf{P}^{\mathsf{E}} = \mathsf{EXP}$, which has no fixed polynomial size circuits. I cannot prove the above question though.

Sure, this is false. $\mathrm{E\subseteq NP}$ implies $\mathrm{EXP=NP=coNP}$ by a padding argument, and as you say, there are languages in EXP that require circuit size $\Omega(n^{k+1})$. (In fact, there are such languages in the polynomial hierarchy. Direct diagonalization gives such a language in $\Sigma^P_4$ or so. The best currently known bound, a recent result of Li, following up on Chen, Hirahara and Ren, is that there is such a language in $\mathrm{S^P_2}$.)

(I meant $\mathrm{O^P_2}$. The $\mathrm{S^P_2}$ result has been known for much longer.)

@EmilJeřábek Thanks! Don't know how I missed the normal padding argument
